# Array in Desending Order

Tags: java

```
Error:(33, 15) java: no suitable method found for sort(int[],java.util.Comparator<java.lang.Object>)
    method java.util.Arrays.<T>sort(T[],java.util.Comparator<? super T>) is not applicable
      (inference variable T has incompatible bounds
        equality constraints: int
        lower bounds: java.lang.Object)
    method java.util.Arrays.<T>sort(T[],int,int,java.util.Comparator<? super T>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
```

I don't understand why num in `Array.sort(num, Collections.reverseOrder())` is wrong?

```
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    int a = s.nextInt();
    int b = s.nextInt();
    int c = s.nextInt();

    int[] num = new int[3];

    num[0] = a;
    num[1] = b;
    num[2] = c;


    Arrays.sort(num, Collections.reverseOrder());
    for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(num[i] + " ");
    }
```

is there any other way to solve it?

Comment: Use `Integer[]` instead.

Comment: For a primitive array, there is no direct way to sort in descending order, unless if you sort the array in ascending order and then reverse it. You need to use an array of `Integer` instead of `int`.

Comment: thank you it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `Arrays.sort` method that accepts an `int[]` and a `Comparator` - the one that accepts a `Comparator` *requests* an array of `Object` or of any subclass of `Object` (example `Integer[]`).

Background information: a type variable (generic) cannot reference a primitive, so

```
<T> void sort(T[], Comparator<? super T>)
```

is not valid for `int[]`.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend you to use Java 8 Streams. I would do it the following:

```
Stream.of(num).sorted(Collections.reverseOrder());
```

If you want to use Arrays.sort() then there is just the optionen for int[] as first parameter to give two more parameters (int fromIndex, int toIndex), which is the reason why you are getting an exception using (int[], Comparator) parameter.

Comment: `Stream` requires terminal operation to activate.  And `Stream.of(num)` returns `Stream<int[]>` instead of `Stream<Integer>`.

Answer (score 0):

Use ArrayList instead

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
   public static void main (String[] args) {
     Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    int a = s.nextInt();
    int b = s.nextInt();
    int c = s.nextInt();

      ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      list.add(a);
      list.add(b);
      list.add(c);
      Comparator c1 = Collections.reverseOrder();
      Collections.sort(list,c1);
      System.out.println("Desending Order : " + list);
   }
}
```

This will do the trick. You can use array in intialization.

The code underneath worked for me using Array

```
import java.util.Arrays; 
import java.util.Collections; 

public class Main 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        Integer[] arr = {2, 1, 3}; 
        Arrays.sort(arr, Collections.reverseOrder()); 
        System.out.printf("Desending Order : %s", Arrays.toString(arr)); 
    } 
}
```